# Xen: How to install bootloader for domU (guest os)?

Tags: centos, debian, xen, host, guest

I tried to install with "grub-install" grub for guest os (which is debian) from host (centos). Tried with chroot, tried with deboostrap, tried with netinstaller. Centos is running on two raid hdd's,under LVM. Lvm volumes are created everything is formated and works. Only bootloader problem left.

Netinstaller just throws me a window with error that grub can't be installed,
debootstrap instructions is not clear for me in [here](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/apds03.html), grub-install doesn't work in chroot, and out of chroot (grub-install /dev/mylvm/partition)

Please can somebody write how to install grub for domU (guest) os from centos?

**Edit:**
For feedback: in domU configuration I set bootloader for pygrub. Then it started ok. Still haven't figured out how to make a successful installation from debian install image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GRUB (inside the guest) would require a BIOS, which in turn Xen can only run if you have hardware-assisted virtualization. grub-install therefore may prove to be useless, the more so if your virtual disk runs without a partition table.

The xen-tools package ships a program called pygrub (looks like grub, but is standalone) that extracts the kernel and initramfs from the virtual disk (with or without partition table) **on the host** and causes xen to start with that. The upside is that kernel updates and modifications of grub/menu.lst inside the guest become "instantly valid".

The older alternative is specifying a kernel image to load in /etc/xen/vm/yourmachine.conf, though you have to manually update yourmachine.conf everytime.